# Can't download Apps from the Appstore

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I can't download Apps from the Appstore to my iPod touch 5.
If I want to download an App, I select "get" then "install", it asks for my password which I fill in. After that, it reads "get", but doesn't download anything.

Comment: which iOS do you use and have you already restarted your iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

- Sign out of the appstore, then sign back in again.
- Backup and restore the iPod Touch